# Map XML to a custom C/C++ function

Tags: c++, c, xml

I come from an Android development background and I would like to know if there's a way to allow XML to execute a C/C++ method? This is similar to Android's onClick event where a method is executed when a event has been received i.e. a button press, but I just want the XML to map and execute the method.

Thanks

Comment: XML is not a programming language. XML cannot "execute" anything. XML is just data.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  In C++ function names may get *mangled* by the compiler (to resolve function overloading).  In C there is no mangling.

Comment: You could write a C or C++ program that reads XML data and executes based on data in the XML file.  You will need an XML library.  Search the internet for "Data driven design".

Answer (score 1):

In general, no.  For example, there is no way to make an XSLT document execute a C++ method.

There are some systems (.Net and XAML spring to mind, but I believe Android is similar), where a dialect of XML is used to define a GUI, and attributes or elements define the functions to be called.  This works better in a language with reflection, where the engine reading the XML can directly call the functions, but with something like GetProcAddress or dlsym you could make it work.